# amazon-linux-extras invoke random.py issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

On amazon linux, ec2 or container, below 2 commands will run into exception. seem the python script will be invoked by amazon-linux-extras, is there any special reason for this behavior?

```
echo "raise Exception()" > random.py
amazon-linux-extras
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .cli import main as cli_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/cli.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .software_catalog import get_catalog, fetch_new_catalog, VERSION_KEY, CatalogError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/software_catalog.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tempfile import gettempdir, NamedTemporaryFile
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "random.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

BTW: I found this issue in our gitlab CI, this random.py crash entire build process.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the `/usr/bin/amazon-linux-extras` command is just a shell script:

```
#> cat /usr/bin/amazon-linux-extras
declare -x CATALOGURL AWSDOMAIN AWSREGION RELEASEVER BASEARCH YUMCONFIG_FILE_NAME
declare -x URL_FORMAT USE_MIRRORLIST SRC_SUFFIX DEBUGINFO_SUFFIX
for config_file_location in /etc /usr/local/etc ${HOME:+"${HOME}/.config/amazon-linux"}; do
        test -r "${config_file_location}/amazon-linux-extras.conf" &&
                . "${config_file_location}/amazon-linux-extras.conf"
done

# Avoid encoding errors because default is ASCII.
if test "$ENVROOT"; then
        PATH=$ENVROOT:$PATH
fi
exec env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 ${PYTHON:-python} -m amazon_linux_extras "$@"
```

However, you can see that it's running python with the command...

```
exec env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 ${PYTHON:-python} -m amazon_linux_extras "$@"
```

The important flag here is `-m`, which runs a module like it was a script - in this case, the `amazon_linux_extras` module installed into `site-packages`.

But the other thing `-m` does is **include the current directory into `sys.path`**, which means your `random.py` file will take precedence over the Python standard library `random` module.

From the [Python documentation describing this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

> If this option is given, the first element of `sys.argv` will be the
> full path to the module file (while the module file is being located,
> the first element will be set to `"-m"`).
>
> **As with the `-c` option, the current directory will be added to the start of `sys.path`**.

---

So basically...your `random.py` supersedes `random` from Python stdlib when you run `amazon-linux-extras` from the same directory where you created `random.py`, and this causes the issues you're seeing because somewhere in the `amazon-linux-extras` module, it attempts to use the `random` module to work with temporary files, and when `import random` is executed, it imports your code that immediately raises.